# MAUI Secure Storage not working in .NET 8

Tags: c#, maui, .net-8.0, maui-blazor

I have updated my MAUI app to .NET 8 and since then my LocalStorage has started to fail. I have noticed that the storage no longer maintains session information correctly, as after a short period of time of minimizing the app, it prompts for login again.

In a component of my code, I have this condition to check that user data is not null (a condition that should only be met if the session was closed voluntarily):

```
if (await storage.GetItem<UserInfo>(LocalStorageKey.UserInfo) == null)
```

Has anyone experienced similar issues or knows what the possible solution might be?

Comment: For more details you can also refer to the official doc: [Secure storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/secure-storage?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android).

Answer (score 0):

> I have updated my MAUI app to .NET 8 and since then my LocalStorage has started to fail. I have noticed that the storage no longer maintains session information correctly, as after a short period of time of minimizing the app, it prompts for login again....

Yes, there are indeed some problems with using SecureStorage, when app is upgraded to .NET 8. And yes, currently .NET 8 has many issues.

You can see [some related issues](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues?q=SecureStorage) on Maui GitHub, e.g. this: [SecureStorage GetAsync not working in .NET 8 MAUI #17706](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/17706). Regarding the problem you encountered, you can also report it on MAUI GitHub issue.